# Connect to online MySQL database in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem with connecting to the database.

```
private static readonly string s_connectionString = "Server=db.inu.hu; Database=patientRegistry;UID=****; Password=****; Port=3306; Trusted_Connection=true";
```

That's my connection string and with this I can't open the connection.

```
 using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(s_connectionString))
  {
      conn.Open();
  }
```

I thought the problem might be that I have a table in the database and need to add that to the connection string.

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: VS says Data Source cannot be empty. ArgumentException was unhandled. In the conn.Open();'s line.

Comment: You're using a `SQLiteConnection` but your question says MySQL... Also, make sure you're looking at connectionstrings.com to make sure your connection string is in the correct format for your target.

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem war that the server using MySQL and I wanted to handle it with SQLite. Thanks for helping!

Comment: What should I Install with nuget to make MySqlConnection and others available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to MySQL or SQLite? You are referencing a `SQLiteConnection` object, but I think you need to be using a `MySqlConnection` connection object instead.

Comment: That might be the solution. Thank you Becca!

Comment: This should be a comment as you only guess and still ask more information, it seems to be useful but for questions about OP use comments instead

Comment: @R3uK since she is new to the site, she most likely doesn't have the ability to comment.

Comment: @ragerory : My bad, Indeed it seems that you cannot comment (even on a question) without 50 rep... Anyway it was in the review queue and now she'll know that comments are made for asking more details and such. See you around